# fprintf issues in RPC C program

Tags: c, rpc

I'm having issues with fprintf in my RPC program. It opens a file but won't read the content into a file. It will print the content using printf but fprint leaves the file blank. How do I fix this issue? Thank you

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include"lab5.h"

char * filename(char *str)
{

    file = str;
    printf("filename = %s\n",file);
    return file;
}

int writefile(char *content)
{
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("recfile.txt", "w");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("File can't be created\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%s\n",content);
    int i = fprintf(fp1, "%s", content);
    printf("i = %d\n",i);
    close(fp1);
    return 1;   
}

int findwordcount(char* searchword)
{
    char *grep;
    int count;
    int status;
    FILE *fp;
    grep = (char*)calloc(150, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(grep, "grep -c \"");
    strcat(grep, searchword);
    strcat(grep, "\" ");
    strcat(grep, "recfile.txt");
    strcat(grep, " > wordcount.txt");
    status = system(grep);
    printf("status = %d\n", status);
    if(status != 0)
    {
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen("wordcount.txt", "r");   
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &count);
        printf("count = %d\n", count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: what's the return value? Also this isn't the problem but you aren't closing `"wordcount.txt"` in `findwordcount()`.

Comment: There's no problem with `writefile()`. Either your `content` is empty or you modify `recfile.txt` somewhere else.

Comment: @KingsIndian he says that `printf` is working so I would guess the later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `int writefile (char *content);` you are currently using `close(fp1);`. Instead to close the file, you should `fclose(fp1)` instead.

Comment: +1: Well spotted.  That also means that there should be compilation errors or warnings (at least that `close()` was not declared).  If not, then the OP needs to turn on more compilation warnings, or get a better compiler.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem.